# How to convert Hex colour value to libgdx colour?

Tags: libgdx

I tried to convert it into RGB first and then divided the values by 255 but the result is not what I wanted. The colour is brighter than the original.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the function valueOf() of the class Color of Libgdx?

Color.valueOf(StringHex);//returns a color from a String hex

The function does the following, as you did not post any code maybe you can spot if something went wrong:

```
/** Returns a new color from a hex string with the format RRGGBBAA.
     * @see #toString() */
    public static Color valueOf (String hex) {
        hex = hex.charAt(0) == '#' ? hex.substring(1) : hex;
        int r = Integer.valueOf(hex.substring(0, 2), 16);
        int g = Integer.valueOf(hex.substring(2, 4), 16);
        int b = Integer.valueOf(hex.substring(4, 6), 16);
        int a = hex.length() != 8 ? 255 : Integer.valueOf(hex.substring(6, 8), 16);
        return new Color(r / 255f, g / 255f, b / 255f, a / 255f);
    }
```